# Joining Two Tables On same Condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables `cafedetails` and `employeedetails`

- `cafedetails` has columns cafemanagerid and staffid
- `employeedetails` has columns employeeid,employeename

I want to get full details

```
cafemanagerid, name, staffid, name
```

My query:

```
select 
    cafemanagerid, employeename as cafemanagerName, 
    staffid, employeename as staffname
from 
    cafedetails, employeedetails
where 
    cafemanagerid = employeeid 
    and staffid = employeeid
```

I know not working but how to achieve this?

Help me..

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `employeedetails` twice, each with different alias names.
In this example, I used a full outer join to show the data if either match.  Nulls may appear is the other does not exist.

```
SELECT 
    cd.cafemanagerid,
    cafe.employeename AS cafemanagerName,
    cd.staffid,
    staf.employeename AS staffname 
FROM 
    cafedetails AS cd
    FULL OUTER JOIN employeedetails AS cafe ON cd.cafemanagerid = cafe.employeeid
    FULL OUTER JOIN employeedetails AS staf ON cd.staffid = staf.employeeid
```

If you want rows where both exist only then change the `FULL OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`